# IE7 is breaking my menu

Tags: css

I am pretty good with css, but can't figure out why my menu is being destroyed by IE7. Looks perfect in all other browsers I tested. First image link is correct. Second image link is how it looks in IE7.

http://www.asingularcreation.com/Forums/download/file.php?id=8368&mode=view/ie8+.jpg
http://www.asingularcreation.com/Forums/download/file.php?id=8367&mode=view/ie7.jpg

Here is the page: http://www.asingularcreation.com/calls-to-artists.php. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to float (or clear) the menu container. It looks like it is causing IE7 to calculate the width incorrectly which forces the menu to flow down, underneath the sub-menu.

```
<div style="height:40px; line-height:40px; float:left; clear:both"><!--Main Menu --></div>
```

Removing the float and clear properties fixes the display in IE7 and also still works in Chrome and IE8 and IE9.

There is a lot of inline styles in the example page so I would also look at moving the CSS into an external file if possible.

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply. I will try what you suggested when I return to my home office this evening and will let you know if it worked.